# How do I remove the "submitted by" text on node display?

Tags: 7, nodes

In Drupal 6 the option to remove that text  was located in the theme settings; where is it in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the "basic page" type, it would be `example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/page/edit`.
For the "article" type, it's `example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/edit`.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been down-voted, but  http://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article is the correct path for the "article" content type. The /edit part doesn't make any difference, as "Edit" is the default tab.

Comment: You are correct, /edit is the MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, so it is loaded even when omitted.

Answer (score 22):

You can find the option by editing the content type settings.

Structure > Content Types > *Type Name*

Click **Edit**

Then uncheck the **Display author and date information.** option in **Display Settings**.

Comment: Where is that in D7? the path is what is need.

Comment: This removes the tiny text which might be needed. This doesn't remove "Submitted by"

Answer (score 3):

Module [Submitted By](https://www.drupal.org/project/submitted_by) is a more fine-grained solution FWIW. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... lets you control the format of the "Submitted by" information on your content per content type. It adds a fieldset to your node edit form called Appearance that lets you put in a tokenized pattern for the text you want to display.
>
> Depends on [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module. Note: This module does not create any data; rather it relies on other modules providing that data through Token.
>
> You might find the [Custom Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) module useful for things that aren't already provided.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to hide the "Submitted by" text in code, which is rather more flexible than the node settings:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['submitted']) {
    $variables['submitted'] = t('!username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
  }
}
```